# PHP - get mysql data for next month

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a database that contains payment amounts and dates for the payments.

example:

```
date = '2016-12-15'
transaction_amount = '250.00'
```

I then have a dashboard that calculates the sum of the payments for the current month, previous month and following month.

For the current years calculations my select works fine. It looks for any dates with that month and year. The issue is when the year changes, the results are not for the intended month. For example, for Dec 2016, I want Jan 2017 but instead I am getting Jan 2016.

How do I continuously calculate the current month, previous month and next month data and take into consideration the change from year to year.

Here is my code:

```
$getlastmonth = mysqli_query("SELECT sum(transaction_amount) as TOTAL 
                            from customer_payment 
                            WHERE YEAR(date)=YEAR(CURDATE()) 
                            and MONTH(date)=MONTH(CURDATE()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                            and status='completed'");

$getthismonth = mysqli_query("SELECT sum(transaction_amount) as TOTAL 
                            from customer_payment 
                            WHERE YEAR(date)=YEAR(CURDATE()) 
                            and MONTH(date)=MONTH(CURDATE()) 
                            and status='completed'");

$getnextmonth = mysqli_query("SELECT sum(transaction_amount) as TOTAL 
                            from customer_payment 
                            WHERE YEAR(date)=YEAR(CURDATE()) 
                            and MONTH(date)=MONTH(CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
                            and status='completed'");
```

I've tried using answers found on S.O. but they all seem to just get the exact day of the next month instead of the date range (start to end of the month).

Comment: what is this `mysql1_query()` should be `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318991/how-do-i-get-next-month-date-from-todays-date-and-insert-it-in-my-database

Comment: Increment the whole date by a month and then it will work. When you just increment the month it cannot know that the year should also be rolled up as well

Comment: If I increment the whole day, it will return the sum of the transactions just for that one day next month, I need the transactions for the whole month.

Comment: you are passing connection to your queries, right? not enough code to support it if you are. and using the same API to connect with.

Comment: you're also not closing any of those statements, anywhere.

Comment: When you increment/decrement the month, do the same to the year as well.

Comment: Yes, I am passing connection to the queries, they queries work fine for the current year.

Comment: If I increment/decrement the current year then I would not get the date I am looking for. So for 2016-12-09 if I increment the year, I would get 2017-01-09 but the following month (Feb 2017) I would get 2018-03-09